# Quickly read data from Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have the code below reading data from an Excel worksheet and converting it to a pipe delimited text file.   It works.  The problem is it's quite slow as I have to read 1 cell at a time in order to add in the pipe.

I wondered if there was a better way to do this i.e. read the data into memory/array in one step and act on it there.

```
public string Process(string filename)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            Excel.Range range;
            string str = "";
            int rCnt = 0;
            int cCnt = 0;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1); //Use the 1st worksheet

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(destpath);
            range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

            for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
            {
                if ((rCnt % 1000) == 0)
                {
                    txtProgress.Text = "Rows processed: "+ rCnt;
                }
                for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
                {
                    str = str + ToStr((range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2) + "|";
                }
                sw.WriteLine(str);
                str = "";

            }

            xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
            xlApp.Quit();
            sw.Close();
            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);
            MessageBox.Show("Complete","Status");
            return "Success";
        }

 public static string ToStr(object readField)
        {
            if ((readField != null))
            {
                if (readField.GetType() != typeof(System.DBNull))
                {
                    return Convert.ToString(readField);
                }
                else
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }

 private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on only performing a read on the excel file content, I suggest you use the ExcelDataReader library [Link](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader), which extracts the worksheetData into a DataSet object.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IExcelDataReader reader = null;
        string FilePath = "PathToExcelFile";

        //Load file into a stream
        FileStream stream = File.Open(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        //Must check file extension to adjust the reader to the excel file type
        if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FilePath).Equals(".xls"))
        {
            reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
        }
        else if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FilePath).Equals(".xlsx"))
        {
            reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
        }

        if (reader != null)
        {
            //Fill DataSet
            System.Data.DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet();
            try
            {
                //Loop through rows for the desired worksheet
                //In this case I use the table index "0" to pick the first worksheet in the workbook
                foreach (DataRow row in result.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    string FirstColumn = row[0].ToString();
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use LinqToExcel nuget package

https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqToExcel/1.10.1

sample code:

```
string path = @"Users.xlsx";
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(path);
return (from c in excel.Worksheet<User>()
    select c).OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't understand <user> I need to pass in Sheet1 as the worksheet name.